# How do I create a lightbox effect for a video that has been created with Html5?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I've created one video using Html 5 video tags. The video is in 3 different formats with a flash fallback.  Is it possible to display it using a 'lightbox' effect.  Below is my code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-   3.2.6.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../stylesheets/styles.css" />
</head> 
<body> 

<div id="videocontent"> 
<video width="640" height="360" preload="auto" controls poster="http://www.synergese.co.uk/testMathsOnline/day3/videos/day3Wel.jpg" tabindex="0" >
<source src="http://www.synergese.co.uk/testMathsOnline/day3/videos/fracWelDay3.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
<source src="http://www.synergese.co.uk/testMathsOnline/day3/videos/fracWelDay3.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
<source src="http://www.synergese.co.uk/testMathsOnline/day3/videos/fracWelDay3.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>

<a href="http://www.synergese.co.uk/testMathsOnline/day3/videos/fracWelDay3.mp4" 
style="display:block;width:640px;height:360px;" 
id="player"></a>
</video> 
</div>

<!-- this script block will install Flowplayer inside previous A tag --> 
<script language="JavaScript"> 
flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf");
</script>   
</body>
```

My javascript skills are very limited, so would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks, Pippa

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there) and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers

Comment: Sorry, tried to use upvote and was told that I needed 15 as reputation

Comment: K do that when you have it. It will prove helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use any lighbox javascript library.  For example jquery-tools overlay:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html

Just take one of the examples in the page and change the overlay content with the HTML of your video player.

Comment: Thanks. If I use Flowplayer though, does that mean I can only use the lightbox for the 'flash fallback'?  I used the code on the 'Overlaying Videos' page: [link]http://flowplayer.org/demos/tools/overlay.html and it seems easy to substitute the flv video with the mp4 video (see code above). Would I be able to use it with the Html 5 video tags above though?

Comment: Yes, there should be any problem to use HTML5 video tag inside a jquery-tools overlay

Answer (score 1):

try this out 
http://videolightbox.com/

Comment: Thanks. It only looks as though I can use flv or mp4 with this option. I would need to be able to use mp4, but I'd also need to target ogv and webm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery lightbox, it is easy to set up: simply download it from http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ and see the **How to Use** section of the page to see how to use it.

Ad@m

Comment: Thanks, but I can only use images with this option, I'd need to be able to use video.

Comment: @Pippa I haven't tested this, but you should be able to use this code: `$("video#videoid").lightbox();` Ad@m